# Getting the name of the input variable from within the function

Tags: python, reflection

If say I have something like:

```
myList = []
```

and a function:

```
def f(a):
    ...
```

and I call the function as such (where `myList` is still of `List` type):

```
f(myList)
```

then within this function itself, is there a way to obtain the name of the variable that is passed in? (i.e. can I get the value `"myList"` as a string from within the function?)

Comment: try dir() or locals() or type(a)

Comment: you need to pass it as string in `f("myList")` to get as string. You can ask more elaborately your requirement. so that SO members can help!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. The name of the list holds the reference to the object, not the other way around.

Though if you know the contents of the list, you can do something like this:

```
a = ["kk","jj"]
for key,value in globals().iteritems():
  if type(value) == list and value == ["kk","jj"]:
    print key
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better just to use `if value == a`, which check for both conditions?